# Check if device has camera in cross platform way

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am writing a cross platform Xamarin.Forms Application where my app uses camera and requests camera permissions from the user at runtime. I am using `Xamarin.Essentials` nuget package to check and request permissions. But before I request camera access permission, I want to make sure the device has camera hardware. Is there any cross platform way to check whether the device has camera hardware? I checked the Xamarin.Essentials documentation and I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Media plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) has this API

```
CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable
```

Comment: I was expecting MediaPlugin as part of Xamarin.Essentials package. If not, at least Xamarin.Essentials should provide a way to check that without relying on MediaPlugin. Thank you anyways, I should be able to add that package and make it work.

Comment: I just realized while installing the Media Plugin nuget package, that it is dependent on Xamarin.Essentials. So I guess it is intentionally separated out

Answer (score 1):

We should use [Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.mediapicker?view=xamarin-essentials) now, as support for [Media plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) officially stopped in Dec 2020:

> Xamarin.Essentials 1.6 introduced official support for [picking/taking photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?WT.mc_id=friends-0000-jamont&tabs=android) with the new Media Picker API. [...]  I will officially be archiving this library in December 2020 [...]

Comment: Does its `IsCaptureSupported` work the same as `IsCameraAvailable` or does it, for example, consider permissions, too?
EDIT: Okay, checked it in GitHub: yes, it does (at least for Android, what is the only thing it's interesting for me).